# Group key-value pairs in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to save data to [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#kotlin) however I want to group the same list of values for different instances. For example:

```
class Player(name: String, age: Int, gender: String) {

}
```

**PlayerDetails.kt**

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {

    val name: String = player_name.text.toString()

    val age = if (player_age.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) player_age.text.toString().toInt() else 0
    val genderId: Int = gender.checkedRadioButtonId
    val gender: String = if (genderId > 0) resources.getResourceEntryName(genderId) else ""

    if (name.isNotEmpty() && genderId > 0 && age > 0 ){

        val player = Player(name, age, gender)

        val sharedPref = this@PlayerDetails.getSharedPreferences("user_details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        ... 
        // get a specific Player's age

    } else {
        blankFields()
    }


}
```

I want the SharedPreferences file to have all the `Player` instances in one file:

**.../shared_prefs/user_details.xml**

```
<map>
    <string name="name">peter</string>
    <string name="age">22</string>
    <string name="gender">male</string>
</map>
<map>
    <string name="name">steven</string>
    <string name="age">24</string>
    <string name="gender">male</string>
</map>
```

How can I access individual `Player` instances (for example Peter's `age`)?

If I perform `sharedPref.getString("age","defaultName")` it can't target a specific player's `age` as there are multiple instances.

Answer (score 2):

This really is not what shared prefs are for. If you want to save complex data locally look into "Room" https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room to add a mini SQL lite database.

Answer (score 1):

Well usually you should use **database** for storing lists or maps.

But if you really want to store it in `SharedPrefences` I can advice you to **serialize** `Map` into `JSON` and then save it in `SharedPreferences`. Its easiest way to solve problem.